# How to avoid memory leaks in this case?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, garbage-collection

In order to prevent memory leaks in ActionScript 3.0, i use a member vector in classes that have to work with vectors, for example:

```
public class A
{
    private var mHelperPointVector:Vector.<Point> = new Vector.<Point>();


    public static GetFirstData():Vector.<Point>
    {
        mHelperPointVector.length = 0;
        ....
        return mHelperPointVector;
    }


    public static GetSecondData():Vector.<Point>
    {
        mHelperPointVector.length = 0;
        ....
        return mHelperPointVector;
    }
}
```

and then i have consumers who uses GetFirstData and GetSecondData methods, storing references to vectors returned by these methods, for example:

```
public function OnEnterFrame():void
{
    var vector:Vector.<Point> = A.GetSecondData();
    ....
}
```

This trick seems to be good, but sometimes i need to process the vector returned by GetSecondData() after some period of time, and in this case, this vector becomes overwritten by another call to GetSecondData() or GetFirstData()...The solution is to copy vector to a new vector...but in this case is better to avoid this trick at all. How do you deal with these problems? I have to work with a big amount of vectors (each of length between 1-10).

Comment: Two vectors of size 10 should not be a problem. I imagine the issue with allocating/creating the new vectors and filling them with values, but would like to see more code( a basic working sample to test with) to know for sure. As an idea, when you do GetFirstData your class A could have a boolean flag to check if it should clear previous data or not. Also, kind of off topic, have a look at Object Pools.

Answer (score 0):

The thing about garbage collection is just trying to avoid instantiating (and disposing of) as much as possible. It's hard to say what would be the best approach since I can't see how/why you're using your Vector data, but at first glance I think that with your approach you'll be constantly losing data (you're pretty much creating the equivalent of weak instances, since they can be easily overwritten) and changing the length of a Vector doesn't really avoid garbage collection (it may delay and reduce it, but you're still constantly throwing data away).

I frankly don't think you'd have memory leaks with point Vectors unless you're leaking the reference to the Vector left and right. In which case, it'd be better to fix these leftover references, rather than simply coming up with a solution to reuse the same vectors (which can have many more adverse effects).

However, if you're *really* concerned about memory, your best solution, I think, is either creating all vectors you need in advance (if it's a fixed number and you know their length ahead of time) or, better yet, using [Object Pools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern). The latter would definitely be a more robust solution, but it requires some setup on your end, both by creating a Pool class and then when using it. To put it in code, once implemented, it would be used like this:

```
// Need a vector with length of 9
var myVector:Vector.<Point> = VectorPool.get(9);

// Use the vector for stuff
...

// Vector not needed anymore, put it back in the pool
VectorPool.put(myVector);
myVector = null; // just so it's clear we can't use it anymore
```

`VectorPool` would control the list of Vectors you have, letting other parts of your code "borrow" vectors as needed (in which they would be marked as being "used" inside the VectorPool) and give them back (marking them back as unused). Your code could also create vectors on the spot (inside `get()`), as needed, if no usable vectors are available within the list of unused objects; this would make it more flexible (not recommended in some cases since you're still spending time with instantiation, but probably negligible in this case).

This is a very macro explanation (you'd still have to write `VectorPool`), but object pools like that are believed to be the definitive solution to avoid re-instantiating as well as garbage collection of objects that are just going to be reused.

For reference, here's what I used as a very generic Object Pool:
https://github.com/zeh/as3/blob/master/com/zehfernando/data/ObjectPool.as

Or a more specialized one, that I use in situations when I need a bunch of throwaway `BitmapData` instances of similar sizes:
https://github.com/zeh/as3/blob/master/com/zehfernando/data/BitmapDataPool.as

I believe the implementation of a VectorPool class in the molds of what you need would be similar to the link above.

As a side note, if performance is a concern, I'd suggest using vectors of fixed length too, e.g.

```
// Create a vector of 9 items, filled with `nulls`
var myPoints:Vector.<Point> = new Vector.<Point>(9, true);
```

This makes it faster since you won't have micro allocations over time. You have to set the items directly, instead of using `push()`:

```
myPoints[0] = new Point(0, 0);
```

But that's actually a forced advantage since setting the vector items is faster than `push()`.